# jQuery ajax - SyntaxError: JSON.parse with fine json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

i have problem. I get a error with the return from php to my ajax call.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

in php i do this

```
echo json_encode(array("message1" => "Hi","message2" => "Something else"));
```

my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "s_save.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log("beforesend: "+data);
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log("form search in db: "+data);
            sendMail(mailName,mailAdress, customertype );
        },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
            console.log(ajaxOptions)
          }
    });
}
```

Now if i look in my firebug i see the answer, what looks good to me.

```
{"message1":"Hi","message2":"Something else"}
```

The Error Section but say this.

```
200

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

parsererror
```

i dont get it. the json return looks fine to me. why do i get the error ?

**EDIT:**

After the first answer i made some changes in the php file, but didnt help
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

```
$output = array("data" => "Hi","message2" => "Something else");
$output = str_replace(' ', '', $output);
echo json_encode($output);
```

**Edit 2**

That was the fix to the problem. thanky everbody for your HELP!

```
Save the file as UTF-8 without BOM. –  Álvaro G. Vicario 12 mins ago
```

Comment: you aren't using the `data`, are you? You need to pass it as parameter to success callback

Comment: I think you have to set specific content type for JSON response in PHP page.

Comment: Have you verified that no extra whitespace or other chars are being outputted ahead of the JSON?

Comment: Make sure there is no other output, e.g. invisible characters.

Comment: @AmitJoki Please look the update part in my post

Comment: @Ragnar Please look the update part in my post

Comment: try contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", in you ajax post and also in your success you're using the data you sent, as you haven't passed data to the success

Comment: @JAAulde how can i see this ? i make a str_replace now but didnt help. you can see it in my starting post under edit

Comment: change the content type to text, change the success to `success: function(result){ console.log(escape(result));` Is the text being returned what you expect? My guess is there is a hidden character in the response that is blowing up the parser.

Comment: @artm i set "application/json; charset=utf-8", now i get "No conversion from text to application/json;" instead of "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". i also set data in the return. you can see this in the edit sectionin my starting post.

Comment: Save the file as UTF-8 **without BOM**.

Comment: @MichAel have you tried setting the content header like in the answer below together with the content in ajax?

Comment: @epascarello changed the content type in my php to text (header('Content-Type: text'); ) and the sucess to success: function(result){ console.log(escape(result));  no i get a result that looks like this "%uFEFF%0D%0A%7B%22data%22%3A%22Hi%22%2C%22message2%22%3A%22Somethingelse%22%7D%0D%0A". its "close" to what i want. without the escape i got this {"data":"Hi","message2":"Somethingelse"} . so want need now would be that i can get the variables one bye one (var data = result.data)something like this.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario You´re my hero of the day. i own you a cup of coffee^^. that was the f´kn problem. Thank you!

Comment: So the leading characters are `%uFEFF%0D%0A` which is a zero width no break space, carriage return, & a line feed. Should not be an issue...

Comment: @artm i tried, but Alvaro git it. saving it without BOM.

Comment: This BOM issue comes in pretty often. There must be like a hundred dupe questions but I'm always unable to find them.

Comment: @epascarello  What ^^ Could you tell me what i have to search for to understand how you can see "zero width no break space" if you see this %uFEFF%0D%0A  ?  BTW. Alvaro git it. saving it without BOM.

Comment: It is unicode http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Answer (score 0):

Set dataType: "html" instead of json.